# Pass the WordPress title in external php file outside WP

Tags: wordpress

How can i get the post/page title in external php file?

I have an external php file where i need to pass the page/post tile originally in WP called:

```
the_title(); // i need to pass the title to external php file outside WP
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the title you can request it outside the loop easily.

Try and call the_title() in your external file. It should work

But you have to be aware that if you don't put a condition, each page of your website will display its title in the header section.

EDIT: the function to call is get_the_title($post->ID) since the_title() doesn't allow you to specify the post id as an argument. You can check on the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) for function allowing you to query information from your post outside the loop.

Comment: I need it in custom php file outside wp the_title() cant work

Comment: What do you mean by a custom php file. Is it a post type or  taxonomy or a archive page or a single post page? I don't understand why you need a custom page. Or is it a ajax call? Can you explain?

Comment: What is need is the following:
When someone click this button on this page or post(inside WP) to get the title and send it to this external php file outside WordPress

Any ideas ?

Comment: You can use ajax

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) it's reliant on [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Not accounting for the fact that you need to at least partially load WordPress to use WordPress specific functions.

Why not just pass it as a query string value?

WordPress Page:

```
<a href="https://example.com/custom-php-script/?t=<?php echo urlencode( get_the_title ); ?>">Click Me</a>
```

PHP Page:

```
<h1><?php echo urldecode( $_GET['t'] ); ?></h1>
```

If you want, you could obfuscate it a little as well.

Alternatively you're looking at processing a POST request, or handing off an ID and loading in `wp-load.php` and processing the ID, which all sound like overkill for something as simple as passing off the title to a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHP file is on the same server as your WordPress install you can use the following to access WP and its resources:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( rtrim( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/' ) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

and then use any WP function. So, for example, you can use

```
$title = get_the_title( $post_ID );
```

or even

```
$post = get_post( $post_ID );
setup_postdata( $post );
the_title();
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved : i'm rebuild the mo po file and problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).